# How to determine 2D coordinates of points given only pairwise distances

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a set of 2D points in which each pair has a known Euclidean distance between them. How can I go about determining an arrangement of them?

I understand there is not a unique solution in general, but for the sake of my question, assume one point is fixed at the origin.

Mathematically, we have $P = \{p \vert p \in R^2\}$ and $D = \{d \in P \times P \vert \| d\| \text{is known} \}$. How can I find a valid arrangement? (Forgive my rustiness with proper set notation)

Note: I feel like least squares may be the best solution. This is related to bundle adjustment in photogrammetry.

Comment: I may not be understanding, but even if you fix one of the points at the origin, there is still no unique solution since only knowing the distance will give you a circle about the origin.

Comment: @Carser: That's fine. I guess I should have specified that. Or left out the fixed point. Or assume that a second point is fixed along the X axis as well (i.e. (X, 0))

Comment: How many points do you have?

Comment: @Paul: >=3 points

Comment: Notice that you can fix two points, not just one.  If you have the first point at the origin, you can also a set a second point at $(d_{12},0)$ where $d_{12}$ is the distance from the first and second points.  If there are only 3 points, there are 2 locations that 3rd point can be (if there are any).  For more than 3 points, you can iterate this process, although there is no guarantee of any solution.

Comment: This is a famous problem, see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry_problem   . The "known" distances are notoriously inaccurate, so that we have in fact  a large optimization problem. Note that in geodesics angles are measured instead, with much less error.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I believe my problem is simpler than that though. For one I assume I have accurate distances, and I am constrained to a plane in 2D space. It seems to me that something like an iterative trilateration where the existing points can be refined is a possible solution? I don't much care that the solution is unique, as I can just shift a desired point to the origin and it only matters that the points are coplanar

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that a solution exists; to check whether a solutions exists requires more iteration.

Notice that you can fix two points, not just one. If you have the first point at the origin, you can also a set a second point at $(d_{12},0)$ where $d_{12}$ is the distance from the first and second points. If there are only 3 points, there are 2 locations that 3rd point can be (if there are any). For more than 3 points, you can iterate this process, picking a pair of points to locate the third.  Since for each step there are 2 possible locations, you may run into a situation that is impossible for a previous choice, so you have to go back and make the opposite choice.