# How to find a geometric arrangement of coplanar points given pairwise distances

Tags: geometry, optimization

This question is building on [a question I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938440/how-to-determine-2d-coordinates-of-points-given-only-pairwise-distances?noredirect=1#comment3979930_1938440). I have formulated the problem more clearly here I believe, and thus the question is searching for a different answer.

We have $N$ points we want to find, and we are given a real $N \times N$ (upper triangular) matrix $D$ where $d_{i,j} \in D$ represents the Euclidean distance between point $i$ and point $j$. I want to find the set of coordinates $ \hat{X} := (\hat{x}, \hat{y})$ that satisfy the distance constraints.

Mathematically I believe this can be written as

$$ \underset{\hat{X_i}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \sum^{N}_{i=1} \sum^{N}_{j=i} \| \hat{X}_i - \hat{X}_j \|_2 - d_{i,j} $$

My question is twofold. Is this an accurate representation, and if so how do I go about solving it? Nonlinear least-squares?

**Note:** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181169/given-the-pairwise-distances-between-n-points-how-can-i-find-plausible-coordi?rq=1) asks essentially the same thing, but the accepted answer only works for 3 points, rather than the general N-point case.

Comment: I don't understand if your $d_{ij}$ are the exact distances or some measured quantity (with some uncertainty). My answer refers to the first case, but reading your question again I think you rather have the second case in mind. Is it so?

Comment: @Aretino: $d_{i,j}$ are considered to be certain (i.e. no error). However, your answer below is only for the case of 3 points. I understand I can establishing a plane, but the additional registered points must maintain their distance from *all* other points, not just the first 3.

Comment: Given the distances of point $k$ from the first three, there is only one possible position for it. In other words: given $d_{1k}$,  $d_{2k}$ and $d_{3k}$ the other distances are redundant: they are not needed to find the position of $\hat X_k$.

Comment: Of course, one must check that the other distances fit with the solution: if that is not the case, then the problem is impossible.

Comment: @Aretino: You're misunderstanding the problem I think. None of the points are fixed. Even those first 3 points' coordinates can be adjusted if necessary in the optimization

Comment: May I suggest you to propose a simple example (e.g. 4 or 5 points)? That might help avoiding misunderstandings.

Comment: Of course the more general solution is formed by the set of points obtained as explained below, to which an arbitrary rotation and an arbitrary translation can be applied. But if you know only the distances between points, there is no way to select one particular solution as "the best one".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose points $\hat X_1$, $\hat X_2$, $\hat X_3$ are not aligned (you can check that, because if they were aligned one among $d_{12}$, $d_{23}$, $d_{31}$ would be the sum of the other two) and fix their position to set up a coordinate system (e.g. $\hat X_1=(0,0)$, $\hat X_2=(d_{12},0)$ and $\hat y_3>0$).

The coordinates of any other point $\hat X_k$ are then fixed by solving the system
$$
\begin{align}
(\hat x_k-\hat x_1)^2+(\hat y_k-\hat y_1)^2=d_{1k}^2\\
(\hat x_k-\hat x_2)^2+(\hat y_k-\hat y_2)^2=d_{2k}^2\\
(\hat x_k-\hat x_3)^2+(\hat y_k-\hat y_3)^2=d_{3k}^2\\
\end{align}
$$

This system has a unique solution (if any), because the equations represent three circles whose centers are not aligned. Any set of points obtained by that through an isometry is of course also a solution.

EDIT.

Let me give an example. I chose five points at random (to keep things simple  their coordinates are integers in the range $[-5,5]$):
$$
P_1=(0,-5),\quad
P_2=(-2,0),\quad
P_3=(-4,-2),\quad
P_4=(4,-4),\quad
P_5=(0,1).
$$
Here's the matrix of their mutual distances:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & \sqrt{29} & 5 & \sqrt{17} & 6 \\
 \sqrt{29} & 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 2 \sqrt{13} & \sqrt{5} \\
 5 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 0 & 2 \sqrt{17} & 5 \\
 \sqrt{17} & 2 \sqrt{13} & 2 \sqrt{17} & 0 & \sqrt{41} \\
 6 & \sqrt{5} & 5 & \sqrt{41} & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Suppose we don't know the coordinates of the points, but just their distances.
We have $d_{12}=\sqrt{29}$, $d_{23}=2 \sqrt{2}$ and $d_{31}=5$:
as none of these numbers is the sum of the other two, the first three points are not aligned. If they were aligned, we would of course choose other three points. We thus proceed as explained above and set: 
$\hat X_1=(0,0)$, $\hat X_2=(\sqrt{29},0)$.

To find point $\hat X_3=(x,y)$ we must solve the system
$$
\begin{cases} 
x^2+y^2=5^2 \\ 
(x-\sqrt{29})^2+y^2=(2 \sqrt{2})^2
\end{cases}
$$
which has the solutions 
$(x,y)=\left(\frac{23}{\sqrt{29}},\pm\frac{14}{\sqrt{29}}\right)$.
We want to pick the solution with $y>0$, so we set: 
$\hat X_3=\left(\frac{23}{\sqrt{29}},\frac{14}{\sqrt{29}}\right)$.

To find point $\hat X_4=(x,y)$ we must solve the system
$$
\begin{cases} 
x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{17})^2 \\ 
(x-\sqrt{29})^2+y^2=(2 \sqrt{13})^2\\
(x-23/\sqrt{29})^2+(y-14/\sqrt{29})^2=(2 \sqrt{17})^2
\end{cases}
$$
which has the only solution 
$\hat X_4=\left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{29}},-\frac{22}{\sqrt{29}}\right)$.

To find point $\hat X_5=(x,y)$ we must solve the system
$$
\begin{cases} 
x^2+y^2=6^2 \\ 
(x-\sqrt{29})^2+y^2=(\sqrt{5})^2\\
(x-23/\sqrt{29})^2+(y-14/\sqrt{29})^2=5^2
\end{cases}
$$
which has the only solution 
$\hat X_5=\left(\frac{30}{\sqrt{29}},-\frac{12}{\sqrt{29}}\right)$.
You can check that the distance between $\hat X_4$ and $\hat X_5$ is indeed $\sqrt{41}$.

As you can see, the points we thus found are not the ones I gave at the beginning. However, they are related to those by an isometry: I represented in the diagram below the original points $P_i$ (red) and the points $\hat X_i$ we found (blue); for the sake of clarity, points are joined by a dashed line, according to their order.

[image]

Comment: I've added a concrete example of the procedure.